# How to detect an empty line in java scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've searched a lot but found nothing that can solve this problem. I'm using [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) to read the input from the user, but if the user enters nothing (just presses enter), it will loop infinitely until the user enters something. But what I want is to stop the program if the user enters nothing, and tell them "this is empty". What should I do? Could someone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compare{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (scan.hasNextInt()){

            int num1 = scan.nextInt();
            int num2 = scan.nextInt();

            int Difference = Math.abs(num2 - num1);

            if (num1 == num2) {
                System.out.println("They are equal");
            }else if (num1 < 0 | num2 < 0){
                System.out.println("No negative number!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Their difference is " + Difference);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter correct number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code which tell us what approach you have followed.

Comment: can also use .nextLine() and check for "" empty string, and use Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the input using `scan.nextLine()` and then check whether user gave an input with a correct pattern IN A SINGLE LINE. You can prompts the user to give the input in a single line separated by a space:

```
System.out.println("Please enter two numbers in a single line separated by a space. (i. e.: 4 12)");
```

You can check the pattern and do your job through split and parsing as folows:

```
if (Pattern.matches("\\d+ \\d+", input)) {
        String[] nums = input.split(" ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
        ....
}
```

The full program is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    if (Pattern.matches("\\d+ \\d+", input)) {
        String[] nums = input.split(" ");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
        if (num1 == num2) {
            System.out.println("They are equal");
        } else if (num1 < 0 || num2 < 0) {
            System.out.println("No negative number!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Their difference is " + Math.abs(num2 - num1));
        }
    } else {
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("This is Empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter correct number");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to make your program supportive to both single line input and double line input, you can refactor the code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter two numbers in a single line separated by a space. (i. e.: 4 12)");
    String input = scan.nextLine().trim();
    if (input.matches("\\d+ \\d+")) {
        doParsingAndCalculation(input);
    } else {
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("This is Empty");
        } else if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
            String secondLine = scan.nextLine().trim();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input);
            if(secondLine.matches("\\d+")) {
                stringBuilder.append(" ").append(secondLine);
                doParsingAndCalculation(stringBuilder.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter correct number");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong! Please enter correct number");
        }
    }
}

private static void doParsingAndCalculation(String input) {
    String[] nums = input.split(" ");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
    if (num1 == num2) {
        System.out.println("They are equal");
    } else if (num1 < 0 || num2 < 0) {
        System.out.println("No negative number!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Their difference is " + Math.abs(num2 - num1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code checks if the user pressed `<Enter>`. If they did then we print out `"User pressed enter"`.
If they pressed something else then we attempt to parse the line as an integer.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // The sc.nextLine() call will retrieve 
        // the line that the user entered.
        String lineEnteredByUser = sc.nextLine();

        // If the user presses an empty line 
        // the lineEnteredByUser variable will contain 
        // the empty String "".
        if ("".equals(lineEnteredByUser)) {
            System.out.println("User pressed enter");

        } else {            
            // If the user entered something else then
            // we try to parse it as an `int` using
            // `Integer.parseInt`. A NumberFormatException
            // might occur if the use did not input an int.   
            int result = Integer.parseInt(lineEnteredByUser); 
            System.out.println("User pressed " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

If we run the above java code (which I placed in a file called `Play.java`) we get the following:

```sh
$ java Play.java
1
User pressed 1

$ java Play.java

User pressed enter

$ java Play.java
1.2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.2"
```

The docs for the functions that I used you can find over here: [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your method but if I enter two integer in one line there will be error, how could I separate them into two int?

Comment: Thanks for your question. It is better to ask this in a new stackoverflow question. This way we keep stackoverflow's FAQ format clear. However, as an ad-hoc solution, if you want to parse multiple integers on 1 line. You can replace the code in the else block with `Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(lineEnteredByUser); while (sc2.hasNextInt()) { System.out.println("next int is: " + sc2.nextInt()); }`

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.hasNext()` will always be true and the loop won't end, because there is always a string input even though it is empty `""`.

You can use this statement: `if(line.length() == 0) break;`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using `nextInt` to read the input from the user, but if the user enters nothing (just presses enter), it will loop infinitely until the user enters something.

That is true, assuming that the `Scanner` reads from standard input.  (The `nextInt` call will just keep reading until it gets non-whitespace characters.)

So if you want to give the user the option of typing ENTER to stop, you should not call `nextInt()` on the `Scanner` directly.  Instead, you could call `nextLine()` to get a complete input line from the user.  Then attempt to parse the line as an integer; e.g. using `new Scanner(theLine).nextInt()`.

There are a number of possible variations on this.

---

If your goal is (literally) just to test for an empty line, then call `Scanner.nextLine()` and test if the result is an empty string.  However, you need to take account of what happened to the scanner *before* you called `nextLine()`.  For example, if the last thing you did was (successfully) call `nextInt()`, then there will still be characters after the number ... on the current line.  You would need to "consume" those characters (with an extra `nextLine()` call) before you can read the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String nextLine = scanner.nextLine() ;
```

you can check  nextLine.equals("")  is an empty string  or not.